# Create an automized heatmap given data lists and function

Tags: python, plot

Given three lists, e.g.

```py
a = [0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
b = [0.3, 0.2, 0.5]
c = [0.1, 0.6, 0.12]
```

I want to generate a confusion matrix, which essentially applies a function (e.g. the correlation) between each of the combinations of the lists.

Essentially the calculations then look like this:

```py
confusion_matrix = np.array([
    [1,
    scipy.stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0],
    scipy.stats.pearsonr(a, c)[0]],
    
    [scipy.stats.pearsonr(b, a)[0],
    1,
    scipy.stats.pearsonr(b, c)[0]],
    
    [scipy.stats.pearsonr(c, a)[0],
    scipy.stats.pearsonr(c, b)[0],
    1]
])
```

Does a Python function exist, which is capable of generating such a matrix automatically, without spelling out every element? If this could also generates a heatmap from the matrix, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a list comprehension:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
from itertools import product

matrix = [a, b, c]
np.array([
    [1 if i1 == i2 else pearsonr(matrix[i1], matrix[i2])[0]
    for i2 in range(len(a))] for i1 in range(len(a))
])
```

This outputs:

```py
[[ 1.          0.65465367  0.03532591]
 [ 0.65465367  1.         -0.73233089]
 [ 0.03532591 -0.73233089  1.        ]]
```